# Are the column width inches in Excel on a Mac the same as those of Windows?

Tags: mac, windows, ms-office

Are the column width inches in Excel on a Mac the same as those of Windows?

I was given homework by my instructor and the width is far too much – so do Excel on OS X and Windows behave the same in that regard?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Why would you think an inch would be different on another platform? Can you provide an example that shows this?

Answer (score 1):

An inch is an inch independently of any application or physical ruler you are using to measure it. So yes, the column widths are the same for the same number of inches on both versions.